# Adding image watermark to map via ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

i need to use a png as a watermark for a map that is generated via javascript api. Don't know how to do that.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/38328

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your map DIV tag, add another DIV tag with the image inside. You can set the transparency and float anywhere inside. Or since using a PNG, make it semi-transparent in advance. Example without CSS part below.

```
<div id='map'>
  <div id='floating'>
    <img src="image.png">
  </div>
</div>
```