# How To Add A Watermark on Mapping/WMS Services 10.3?

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, wms, arcgis-10.3

In Geoserver you can add a [watermark](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/services/WMS.html) to your service. Any thoughts on how I can do this on a mapping or WMS service via ArcServer 10.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esri has announced for the next ArcGIS-server version (10.3.1) support of SOI (server object interceptor).

You find some informations about it in this pdf:
 http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc14/tech-workshops/tw_689.pdf

You can also check this video which includes complete explications and a demo of a watermark example:
 [http://video.esri.com/watch/4230/arcgis-server-*and*-sois](http://video.esri.com/watch/4230/arcgis-server-_and_-sois)

Answer (score 1):

[ESRI has a help article on adding a watermark to a map service](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40192).

If you have a web app that consumes the service you could easily add a watermark to the app.
[Here is an example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134072/adding-image-watermark-to-map-via-arcgis-api-for-javascript) of doing that with the JavaScript API.

Comment: Both methods work, however I can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 0):

here you can see a preview of soi (ags 10.3.1 in java):

https://github.com/mraad/ExportImageSOI

In this code there is override to handleRESTRequest. If there is a request of export and image the function call custom doExportImage for watermark otherwise follow the request from client.